# I am trying to understand what chara ito means

Tags: translation

I am currently translating a Japanese text in English and I have trouble understanding this text.

> 貴族的というのか、イケメンだけどチャラいとは程遠い

I get and can make out some part of the sentence like 'he looks like an aristocrat' but after the chara ito part starts I don't get it.

Comment: Please show efforts in translating it. ex: Have you tried searching the word チャラい before? If so, did you understand it, or do you still have trouble?

Comment: yeah, I searched but still had to wrack my brain to find the meaning. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

He's more like aristocrat, good looking but far from being flirty.

Hard to explain but チャラい contains the meanings of flirtatiousness, gaudiness, vulgarness.